# How to get a value from a HTML textbox, written in JavaScript, in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm currently busy with a database project. The idea is that you can select an option and when some options are selected the HTML form changes. I've got that all going, the only problem I have got now is that the PHP file, to which the form redirects, doesn't recognize the textbox which is placed there by a JavaScript function.

JavaScript and HTML:

```
<head>
<script>
function myFunction(submittedValue) {
if(submittedValue == "URL"){
var x = "URL:";
var y = "<input type='text' name='URL'>";
} else {
var x = "Bestand:";
var y = "<input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'>";
}
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = y;
} 
</script>
</head>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction('URL')">
<table>
<form action='Brontoevoegen_verwerking1.php' method='POST'  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<tr><td><p id='x'></p></td><td><p id='y'>N/p></td></tr>
</table>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$URL = $_POST["URL"];
echo "$URL";
?>
```

Whenever I execute the PHP file I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: URL in /home/******/http/Brontoevoegen_verwerking1.php on line 15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input doesn't even end up in the form at all, you end up with

```
<table>
    <form action="Brontoevoegen_verwerking1.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    </form>

    <!-- form closed :O -->

    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>
               <p id="x">URL:</p>
           </td>
           <td>
               <p id="y">
                  <input type="text" name="URL">
               </p>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

because your HTML is invalid, you can't have a form element as a direct child in a table, or rows and cells directly in a form etc.

Comment: alright, never mind. When I set the <form> line above the <table> line, everything just worked fine.

Comment: Yes, you can have a table inside a form, and you can even have a form inside a table, but a table can't have a form as a direct child, you need to know the basics of HTML.